# How to call SSL enabled soap webservice from VB.net or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, ssl, soap

Hello everyone I am trying to access soap webservice which is over https/ssl enabled. But I am getting this error :

> System.Net.WebException was unhandled
>
> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Below is the code I am using to make call.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim url As String = "https://10.31.171.199:8443/emc-dfs/services/core/ObjectService?WSDL"
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ValidateRemoteCertificate)
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
    Dim responsestring As String = ""
    Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    Dim proxy As IWebProxy = CType(myReq.Proxy, IWebProxy)
    Dim proxyaddress As String
    Dim myProxy As New WebProxy()
    Dim response As String


    myReq.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = False
    myReq.Method = "GET"
    myReq.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"
    myReq.PreAuthenticate = True
    proxyaddress = proxy.GetProxy(myReq.RequestUri).ToString

    Dim newUri As New Uri(proxyaddress)
    myProxy.Address = newUri
    Dim myResponse As HttpWebResponse = myReq.GetResponse

    Dim responsedata As Stream = myResponse.GetResponseStream
    Dim responsereader As New StreamReader(responsedata)

    response = responsereader.ReadToEnd
End Sub
```

I am getting this error on line "*Dim myResponse As HttpWebResponse = myReq.GetResponse*".

Please help me what is the issue and how can I call this service. Please help me with any working sample code for SSL soap service.

Thanks.

Comment: Use fiddler to capture html.  You can compare your application results with similar results using IE browser.  Compare the Http headers in IE and your application.

Answer (score 0):

Possible that the version if TLS on the server *isn't* 1.0?  Try:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Barring that, see if setting up a certificate validation delegate to bypass the check works, i.e., right before the call to the request method:
`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function() Return True`

Comment: TLS version is 1.0 on the server also I have bypassed the certificate validation in the code, still it doesnt work.

Comment: Is this an internal service you're trying to establish a connection to or external (public) service?  Have you tried what @jdweng suggested with Fiddler/IE?

Comment: Also: could you be missing any required credentials in your SOAP envelope headers for authorization (i.e.: [https://community.emc.com/message/536141#536141]?